# when I hover over a dynamically created row, the select element(tag) options in the row do not properly drop down. Firefox issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

i have dynamically created rows and I would like it that when I hover over a row a div gets appended to the row and when I hover off the row the div should disappear. I basically got that to work, it's just that one of the td's in the hovered row is a select element and since I implemented the hover effect I was not able to select the options because the options did not drop down correctly. can you tell me why?

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/mSsqa/) for illustration

Hmm I was just testing this out on chrome and the options are coming down like its supposed to. But I do my developing in firefox and the problem above is relevent to firefox but not to chrome. that sucks.any suggestions on getting to work on firefox.

```
$(".row").hover(function(){
    //checks to see if the new div(cancel) exist if it doest append it to the row
    if($(this).children(".cancel").length == 0){
        $("<div class = 'cancel'>X</div>").appendTo($(this));

    //clicking on the div should remove the row
        $(".cancel").click(function(){
               $(this).parent().hide('slow', function(){
               $(this).remove();
       })

    }  
}, function(){
    $(this).find("div.cancel").remove();
})
```

I think it might have something to do with event bubbling or propagation or my logic.
[***Jsfiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jack2ky/mSsqa/)
Thank you for your help

Comment: A JSfiddle would be useful.

Comment: sorry about that, I added the jsfiddle

Comment: I have tested your fiddle in both chrome and fire fox. The line `<div class = 'cancel'>X</div>` is getting added to the DOM in  both the cases , but the `X` is not being shown in either browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your fiddle in firefox. It seems that problem is with below line:

```
$("<div class = 'cancel'>X</div>").appendTo($(this));
```

Everytime, on hover you are appending one div to the row and removing it. Instead of that append div while creating row and hide it. On hover show div. This solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out the problem piece , which is this line of code :

```
var tr = "<tr class = 'row' style='display:block;'><td>"+ suggestion.value + "</td><td><select class ='select' >" + select + "</select><td class = 'price'>" +suggestion.price+ "</td><td class = 'total'></td></tr>";
```

Here, if you see carefully, i have added this piece : `style='display:block;'` to your tr construction. In the previous cases, your tr did not have any style and the DOM itself was constructing the style as : `style=""`. As a result of no styling being their in the row, the `X` icon was not appearing .

Find the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/mSsqa/3/

Tested in both fire fox and chrome .

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't see a working solution. I would like to be able to hover over the row and the "cancel" div should be displayed and I should also be able to select the options from the select tag. I see the select tag is working but the div doesnt appear. Also I noticed that the tr is not aligned to the th making me think that the tr is not in the table. I didnt use firebug to inspect it I just looked at the  link you supplied.http://jsfiddle.net/mSsqa/3/